# MS Project - Rollup not working to main task when not using predecessors

Tags: ms-project

Can somebody help me with below. I am trying to get the correct numbers on the task Name Test Project. I would expect to see 24 hours on the duration. This only works when I use predecessors, which is weird as both task have a different resource so they can work on different tasks at the same time.

Task calendar of resources and task is Standard
Different resource per task
Not sure if it's related but I found the field Rollup and changed it to YES for all

Not working!

[image]

Working! but I do not want to use predecessors

[image: s w]

Answer (score 2):

**Duration** is the working time between the Start and Finish date. Both of these screen shots show the correct duration. There are 16 working hours between the beginning of Monday and the end of Tuesday and there are 24 working hours if it spans until the end of Wednesday.

Since you are using Resources, you can look at the **Work** field to see the total amount of work, which will be 24 hours in both cases. Insert the Work column by selecting an existing column in the table, right-click, then choose Insert Column.

Comment: See [celoxis.com/article/duration-vs-effort](https://www.celoxis.com/article/duration-vs-effort) and [celoxis.com/article/dwu-basics](https://www.celoxis.com/article/dwu-basics) for more info.